# How to write jUnit test cases for Database Components?

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, jenkins

I'm a newbie in jUnit, have a task to write jUnit test cases for application which have some Complex database components. I can write test cases for DB components and those are running fine on my local maven build creation. But in deployment box I dont have DB available while creating build from jenkins maven command. please suggest!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [dbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) extension to jUnit, which aims at creating a known reproducable state between test runs. Used with an in-memory DB such as HSQL or H2 on your CI box  (as well as locally) should suit you just fine.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

A usual approach would be to write unit tests for CRUD functionality on an in-memory database environment.  Not exactly the real thing, but way less dangerous.  Have a look at

http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/javadb-10-5-142692.html

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your tests on unit tests based on mocks and integration tests which run on real DB. Run unit tests only in Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

```
I am working same kind of project. In our application we use test schema and a reusable class which loads the data from the XML(File is same as test class) and Cache the data and removes the data from the table, so that Unit test get intended data. 
We set different profile and these are set via JVM arguments. And these profile have the database details and any other admin stuff required. In case of Junit to run we use the unit test profile.
```